# You made the cut?

Tags: interpretation, jokes

Here's from a TV show "3rd Rock From the Sun S1E06 Green Eyed Dick".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgBb9-xaV3Y

5:42

> Hey! It says "men" on the door.
>
> You made the cut?
>
> (Laugh)

I don't understand what "You made the cut?" means and why it's funny.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*You made the cut* means that you qualified for something.  It is used in theater and sports.  A director might start with a large pool of aspiring actors and only a few roles. Some people will be in the play, and some people will be *cut*.  Those who are in the play made it past the cut, or more commonly *made the cut.*  The expression is widely to describe results of decision making processes.

It is "funny" because it implies that the person under scrutiny is barely a man.